# How to access parent Iframe from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Well, I have an IFrame, which calls a same domain page.
My problem is that I want to access some information from this parent Iframe from this called page (from JavaScript). How can I access this Iframe?

Details: There are several Iframes just like this one, that can have the same page loaded, because I am programming a Windows environment. I intend to close this Iframe, that's why I need to know which I should close from inside him. I have an array keeping references to these Iframes.

EDIT: There iframes are generated dynamically

Comment: even if iframes are generated dynamically, you can assign a new unique id by using some sort of counter, finally you dont need to know ID, but you can search easily, see my answer.

Answer (score 156):

Also you can set name and ID to equal values

```
<iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" src="any.html"></iframe>
```

so you will be able to use next code inside child page

```
parent.document.getElementById(window.name);
```

Comment: Maybe it is not obvious for everyone, but with this method you can access a library object of the parent (only if the parent has already loaded the library). Example: access jQuery with parent.$('#something')

Comment: This solution is compatible with IE5+ compatibility quirks mode.

Comment: Even in 2016, this works great as part of a solution for the problem of IE printing the contents of an `iframe` too small. But why does it work? `window.name` returns a string. What's different about using `window.name` than just passing the id name as a string which doesn't work.)?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't run with Chrome 59.. :VM111:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://xxx" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Chrome see files in same folder as cross-origin if not CORS is set. They say it is for security. Setting CORS need a server. Give users a message to set up a server or change browser if Chrome is detected.

Answer (score 109):

Simply call [`window.frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frameElement) from your framed page.
If the page is not in a frame then `frameElement` will be `null`.

The other way (getting the window element inside a frame is less trivial) but for sake of completeness:

```
/**
 * @param f, iframe or frame element
 * @return Window object inside the given frame
 * @effect will append f to document.body if f not yet part of the DOM
 * @see Window.frameElement
 * @usage myFrame.document = getFramedWindow(myFrame).document;
 */
function getFramedWindow(f)
{
    if(f.parentNode == null)
        f = document.body.appendChild(f);
    var w = (f.contentWindow || f.contentDocument);
    if(w && w.nodeType && w.nodeType==9)
        w = (w.defaultView || w.parentWindow);
    return w;
}
```

Comment: `window.frameElement` returns `null` when window and iframe have different domains, i.e. cross-origin messaging.

Comment: @Qwerty have you found any solution?

Comment: @AjayPatidar I think I gave up. :(

Comment: @Qwerty One possible solution is to use an iframe as a "proxy" to send messages between pages on different domains. [sysend.js](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js) does this using `postMessage()`, for example.

Answer (score 96):

I would recommend using the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

In your iframe, call:

```
window.parent.postMessage({message: 'Hello world'}, 'http://localhost/');
```

In the page you're including the iframe you can listen for events like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      if(event.origin === 'http://localhost/')
      {
        alert('Received message: ' + event.data.message);
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Origin not allowed!');
      }

    }, false);
```

By the way, it is also possible to do calls to other windows, and not only iframes.

Read more about the postMessage API on John Resigs blog [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/postmessage-api-changes/)

Comment: I think this is clearly the best answer, the `<iframe>` contents doesn't have to know anything about the parent and vice versa. They only have to obey the simple message contract. Awesome!

Comment: The <iframe> still has to know the parent's domain, right?

Comment: @HomrZodyssey The parent domain is only available as a safety mechanism, if not known, you can set `'*'`.

Comment: Use `'*'` on clients. Every other solutions give error on a Chrome browser treating files in clients folder as not be Same Origin because a server is not set up. This is the best and *only* solution: https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/postmessage

Comment: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 33):

Old question, but I just had this same issue and found a way to get the iframe. It's simply a matter of iterating through the parent window's frames[] array and testing each frame's contentWindow against the window in which your code is running. Example:

```
var arrFrames = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME");
for (var i = 0; i < arrFrames.length; i++) {
  if (arrFrames[i].contentWindow === window) alert("yay!");
}
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
parent.$("iframe").each(function(iel, el) {
  if(el.contentWindow === window) alert("got it");
});
```

This method saves assigning an ID to each iframe, which is good in your case as they are dynamically created. I couldn't find a more direct way, since you can't get the iframe element using window.parent - it goes straight to the parent window element (skipping the iframe). So looping through them seems the only way, unless you want to use IDs.

Comment: Update: this didn't work exactly as advertised, and I had to use contentWindow.document===document. No idea why. Also in some browsers I used contentDocument. Well, I like that!

Comment: Apologies, admittedly I only tested it in Firefox. :) However I've had success using the jQuery method and contentWindow in multiple browsers.

Comment: Update: I found out that you can also use window.frameElement, but I am not sure which browsers support it.

Comment: I don't think this type of stuff works anymore; you get a cross-origin error.

Comment: @AndrewMao the question is about same origin documents, so no reason to get cross-origin issues.

Answer (score 25):

you can use `parent` to access the parent page.   So to access a function it would be:

```
var obj = parent.getElementById('foo');
```

Comment: Kevin, the problem is to KNOW the id. I have several Iframes, and I want to access them from the code inside

Comment: Still get "Blocked a frame with origin "http://other-localhost:8000" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 15):

Once id of iframe is set, you can access iframe from inner document as shown below.

```
var iframe = parent.document.getElementById(frameElement.id);
```

Works well in IE, Chrome and FF.

Comment: This seems a convoluted way of doing `var iframe = frameElement`

Comment: frameElement returns object in current window context, but parent.document.getElementById(frameElement.id) returns object in parent window context, you can't run parent window's javascript functions with frameElement, try it in jsfiddle and give me and example if you can.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe just use

```js
window.parent
```

into your iframe to get the calling frame / windows. If you had multiple calling frame, you can use

```js
window.top
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, in your parent frame set up you IFRAMEs like this:

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="inner.html#frame1"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" src="inner.html#frame2"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame3" src="inner.html#frame3"></iframe>
```

Note that the id of each frame is passed as an anchor in the src.

then in your inner html you can access the id of the frame it is loaded in via location.hash:

```
<button onclick="alert('I am frame: ' + location.hash.substr(1))">Who Am I?</button>
```

then you can access parent.document.getElementById() to access the iframe tag from inside the iframe

Comment: Yes, this would be the most logical solution, but sometimes I need to change the src of the iframe.. and passing this hash or GET parameter each request is not good..

Comment: why is it bad to pass the hash each time? It is only visible to the browser, not the server, and it doesn't affect caching like a get parameter would.

Answer (score -2):

```
// just in case some one is searching for a solution
function get_parent_frame_dom_element(win)
{
    win = (win || window);
    var parentJQuery = window.parent.jQuery;
    var ifrms = parentJQuery("iframe.upload_iframe");
    for (var i = 0; i < ifrms.length; i++)
    {
        if (ifrms[i].contentDocument === win.document)
            return ifrms[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```