# accessing php javascript object in asp.net user control

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript, object, user-controls

I have a website in php which is using 4 frames(top, left, middle and right). The middle frame 
contains the web user control coded in asp.net. Now, in the right frame( which is coded in php ) some javascript contains the id of the items selected in right frame. I need to get those ids to the middle frame on asp.net user control. How can i do this?

Comment: Are all pages on the same domain?

Comment: yes, they are all on same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the parent page and then access all its iframes.

Some answers to doing that are here:

[How to access parent Iframe from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

[Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

etc.