# How to manage dependencies in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, lazy-loading, settimeout

I have scripts that needs to wait for certain conditions to be met before they run - for example wait for another script to be loaded, or wait for a data object to be created.

How can I manage such dependencies? The only way I can think of is to use setTimeout to loop in short intervals and check the existence of functions or objects. Is there a better way?

And if setTimeout is the only choice, what is a reasonable time interval to poll my page? 50 ms, 100 ms?

[Edit] some of my scripts collect data, either from the page itself or from Web services, sometimes from a combination of multiple sources. The data can be ready anytime, either before or after the page has loaded. Other scripts render the data (for example to build charts).

[update] thanks for the useful answers. I agree that I shouldn't reinvent the wheel, but if I use a library, at least I'd like to understand the logic behind (is it just a fancy timeout?) to try and anticipate the performance impact on my page.

Comment: Check out [LAB.js](http://labjs.com) or another similar script loader.

Comment: setTimeout isn't your best option, can you provide further details? why can't you lunch your script for the script being loaded?

Comment: The script needs several conditions to be met: both data to be present and functions to be loaded. It doesn't depend on just another script.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a function call like `loaded(xyz);` at the end of the scripts that are being loaded. This function would be defined elsewhere and set up to call registered callbacks based on the value of `xyz`. `xyz`can be anything, a simple string to identify the script, or a complex object or function or whatever.

---

Or just use [`jQuery.getScript(url [, success(data, textStatus)] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Answer (score 1):

For scripts that have dependencies on each other, use a module system like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

For loading data remotely, use a callback, e.g.

```
$.get("/some/data", "json").then(function (data) {
    // now i've got my data; no polling needed.
});
```

Here's an example of these two in combination:

```
// renderer.js
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    exports.render = function (data, element) {
        // obviously more sophisticated in the real world.
        element.innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
    };
});

// main.js
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var renderer = require("./renderer");

    $(function () {
        var elToRenderInto = document.getElementById("#render-here");

        $("#fetch-and-render-button").on("click", function () {
            $.get("/some/data", "json").then(function (data) {
                renderer.render(data, elToRenderTo);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The issue in my case is that I have control on the script that consumes the functions and data, not the scripts that load them. That's what I tried to explain in my edit.

Comment: Oh, if you don't have control, then you're screwed, and I guess polling is the only option that comes to mind. Maybe those scripts give some kind of hook for you? E.g. firing a custom event you can subscribe to.

Comment: I actually posted a question about script onload here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956414/cross-browser-onload-event-in-a-static-script-tag . +1 thx for the info about jQuery deferred/then.

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks for this kind of thing.

I'm using Backbone at the moment http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Friends have also recommended knockout.js http://knockoutjs.com/

Both of these use an MVC pattern to update views once data has been loaded by a model

[update] I think at their most basic level these libraries are using callback functions and event listeners to update the various parts of the page.

e.g.

```
model1.loadData = function(){
    $.get('http://example.com/model1', function(response){
        this.save(response);
        this.emit('change');
    });
}

model1.bind('change',view1.update);
model1.bind('change',view2.update);
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I'm looking for. Do you think such frameworks could also monitor when scripts are loaded, or do I need to combine them with libraries mentioned in other replies?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [pxLoader](http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/), a JavaScript Preloader, which works pretty well. It uses 100ms polling by default.

I wouldn't bother reinventing the wheel here unless you need something *really* custom, so give that (or any JavaScript preloader library really) a look.