# How can I execute a javascript function on the parent page from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, file-upload

I'm trying to change text on a page from an iframe on the page. When the user finishes uploading an image I want to change text saying loading... to finished uploading or something. Can this be done from an iFrame? I know when you use `alert("Finished");` it alerts the user from the iframe, but I still have the loading text.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript

Comment: Just want to point out that if the page in the iframe is on a different server you can have issues. Browsers have some built-in protection from cross-scripting, so sending data between a parent window and and iframe can be challenging. Plus FF and IE work differently, so I would definitely test in latest FF and IE 7 through 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using window.parent from within the iframe.  This will point to the parent window.

You could execute a function (named, say, hideLoadingText) within the context of the parent window by doing window.parent.hideLoadingText();

Answer (score 1):

on parent.html page (where there is an iframe)

```
function finished()
{
 //you can change this below line depend on your needs
 document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Finish"; 
}

<span id="status"></span>
<iframe src="child.html" name="iframe_content"></iframe>
```

then you can try this on child.html page (content inside the iframe)

```
<input type="button" value="Finish" onclick="parent.finished()" />
```

also you can change the triger of the function depend on your needs

Answer (score 0):

window.parent.yourjavascriptmethodname();

Comment: Don't just put one-line code snippets, some explanation is appreciated on StackOverflow