# Jquery Get closest() Iframe of an A-tag returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-8, offset

I'm calling a function in my javascript at onmouseover. In the function call I include the srcElement (which is an a-tag). Now I need to get the offsetWidth of the closest Iframe of that a-tag. But when i try this:

```
alert($(srcElement).closest('iframe').offset().left);
```

I get undefined! This doesn't work either:

```
alert($(srcElement).closest('iframe').attr('title'));
```

But this works and returns the id of the body inside the iframe:

```
alert($(srcElement).closest('body').attr('id'));
```

This is my function call in the html:

```
showPeopleDetails('User_Matt', event.clientX, event.clientY, event.srcElement);
```

This is the javascript function:

```
function showPeopleDetailsNow(UserId, x, y, srcElement){
   currentwidth = $(document).width();
   currentheight = $(document).height();
   adjustwidth = $(srcElement).closest('iframe').offset().left;
   adjustheight = $(srcElement).closest('iframe').offset().top;
   var calculatedheight = currentheight - adjustheight;
   var calculatedwidth = currentwidth - adjustwidth;
```

Right now I'm doing it this way, but this only works for one part of my page. As the id is generated dynamically by a framework.

```
   adjustwidth = parent.document.getElementById('ivuFrm_page0ivu0').contentWindow.document.getElementById('ivuFrm_page0ivu2').offsetWidth;
   adjustheight = parent.document.getElementById('ivuFrm_page0ivu0').contentWindow.document.getElementById('ivuFrm_page0ivu2').offsetHeight;
```

Is there any way to get the offset from the body tag (and would it be the correct offset of the iframe? I know that I can get the width of the body-element, but it is not accurate by a few px...  Obviously even better would be the correct offset of the Iframe!
The Iframe has the same port, protocol and host as the original page. I only need it to work with internet explorer 8.
Help is much appreciated!

Update: After proposed solution from Felix Kling and scr4ve I found out that I can't use the offset of the body element or the html element! Since both offsets return 0, I assume that the Iframe element is the only object in the dom who has the correct offset relative to the document. Any suggestions how to get that specific offset?

Comment: The problem is that the `iframe` belongs to the outer document and not to the inner one. The `iframe` does not exist in inner documents hierarchy, `html` is always the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more research on the subject I found the solution to my problem, by basing it on the solution provided by ingredient_15939 in this stackoverflow question: [Access Parent Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript) As Felix Kling suggested the IFRAME does not exist in the document hierarchy, so I search all Iframes for the matching body of my a tag. My final code works as follows:

```
var searchbody = $(srcElement).closest('body');
var arrFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

for(i = 0; i<arrFrames.length; i++){
    //I search and compare every IFRAME to the closest body of my srcElement
    try{
        if(arrFrames[i].id != 'PeopleDetailsIframe'){
            if($(arrFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body).is(searchbody)){
        //The found IFrame has to be the one containing my a-tag
                offsetwidth = $(arrFrames[i]).offset().left;
                offsetheight = $(arrFrames[i]).offset().top;
             }
             else{
                  //console.log("Iframe not found");
             }
         }
      }
      catch(e){
                //Iframe has security issues --> avoid it
      } 
}
```

Hope this can help someone else as well!

Answer (score 0):

<s>According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest), .closest() only considers <s>direct</s> ancestors. I guess your iframe is not a <s>direct</s> parent of your a-tag? Have a closer look at the docs for [Tree Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/). 
[.silbings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) may match your needs.</s>

By the way, consider using console.log rather than alert.

Update after clarification: `$("html").offset()` is suffcient and more performant in this case. There's only one html tag in the frame, no need for `.closest()`. OP might be interested in [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth) / Height, too.

Comment: `direct ancestors !== direct parent` . Ultimately, the whole document is inside the `iframe` so one could think of it as the ancestor of every node inside the document.

Comment: I am talking about `<body><a/><iframe/></body>`. You're talking about `<body><iframe><a/></iframe></body>`. I'm quite not sure what the real problem looks like.

Comment: True. But from the fact that the OP mentions the `body` element, I suspect the link being inside the iframe.

Comment: Yes! Sry for the late reply, but the link is indeed in the iframe. And I need to traverse the DOM-Tree up to the closest iframe of that link. Which is the particular Iframe I want. For now I'm getting the width of the closest body-element, which is the body element of the iframe, but as said it is a few px inaccurate.

Comment: Well you're right. OP fooled me by using `.closest()` unnecessarily.  `$("html").offset()` is sufficient and more performant.

Comment: Yes but if I use $("html").offset() I get the offset value of the original page-> because my script is included in the original page and not the iframe. The link inside the iframe just calls the function in my script hence I use srcElement (to let the script "know" where I am.) Or am I misunderstanding you comment?