# How do you make an iframe run a Javascript function on the main page when the iframe loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ajax-upload

I have this HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function uploadDone(response) {
                                alert(response);
                            }
                            function init() {
                                        document.getElementById('file_upload_form').onsubmit=function() {
                                            document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; //'upload_target' is the name of the iframe
                                            document.getElementById("upload_target").onload = uploadDone(response);
                                        }
                                    }
                        </script>
                        <form method="get" id="file_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../includes/parsecsv.ajax.php" target="upload_target">
                            <label class="uploadClick">
                                <button class="normal">Click to Upload Sign Ups CSV</button>
                                <input type="file" id="uploadSignups file" name="file">
                            </label>
                            <span class="uploadDrag"><span>or</span>Drag Your Sign Ups CSV Here</span>
                            <button type="submit" name="action">hello</button>
                            <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:none;"></iframe>
                        </form>
```

It is supposed to, when you click the submit button, upload the selected file in the file input ajaxically through an `<iframe>`. I seem to have been able to get it to do the uploading, but it does not seem to run `uploadDone()` when the uploading is complete? Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Comment: Form contains enctype=multipart/form-data, but does not contain method=post. Submitting normally with method=GET and no enctype instead.       - and when is your uploadDone() func is triggering

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would just add an event to the iFrame's window element:

```
document.getElementById("upload_target").contentWindow.onload = function(response) { uploadDone(response) };
```

Also, notice I'm wrapping the `uploadDone` inside a function; otherwise, it would just call it and set the event as whatever it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parent property of the IFrame, [How to access parent Iframe from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to create a JSP file which will have the response and
write some script in JSP to access the `uploadDone` method, which is already loaded in document.

The script in JSP can be something like:

```
 parent.document.uploadDone(response);
```

Comment: Please do not use SMS-speak ('Here, u need') in SO; spell words out in full.