# Can I run a script from within an iframe that utilised the time function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it's possible to load a bit of JavaScript from within an iframe. It seems that this questions has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript).

However, the reason I ask is that the iframe is loaded from an external source (i.e. an adserver) and then get's the time from the users machine. What I am trying to do is calculate how long is spent on the page when this iframe is loaded (and then potentially pass this value back to a server).

I know there aren't any code samples in this questions but if someone has come across something like this before please let me know. I always thought there would be some sort of security issue with this i.e. calling an iframe on a page and then that iframe running a script which effectively "gets" something (even if it's just the time) from your machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot communicate with the contents of an Iframe that is served by a different domain due to the **Same Origin Policy**. This is a security feature that prevents framed content from taking over the host page and other types of scripting attacks.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this; I thought as much. Just had a quick read of these. So if I was to say count how long a page had been loaded for, I would need to have that as a script on that particular page?

Answer (score 0):

The `iframe` has an `onload` event which fires when the contents have finished loading. You could grab the time that your page loaded at and then subtract it from the time that the `iframe`'s `onload` event finishes.

Comment: Cool thanks, this is the kind of thing I was thinking of but what I am actually trying to do is determine how long the parent page (which contains the iframe) was loaded for, from within the iframe. But thanks all the same