# Iframe Javascript call to Flex

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a flex application with an iframe layered on top.

I want to make a call from the iframe to flex with javascript.

So far i have tried this:

This is the Object containing the swf embed in the ROOT document

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        id="IPRS_Dispatcher" width="1400" height="1000"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="DispatcherMain.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <!-- <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" /> -->
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name='flashVars' value='strLang=english&strIPRSSrvHost=&strGPSSrvHost=192.168.1.130&strGPSSrvSoapPort=8081&strGPSSrvFwdPort=26000&strLoginMode=simple&strSOSSrvHost=192.168.1.80&strSOSSrvSoapPort=8082&strSOSSrvFwdPort=26001&strSOSLoginMode=simple&strUserSIP=&strUserPswd=&nDelayForMapReadySecs=10&nGPSUpdatesRateSecs=120&nGPSSubscriptionsIntervalMinutes=10&nLat=35.0&nLng=32.5&nZoomLevel=5&strClientServiceVersion=2.1.36.19&nPathDotsSize=1&nPathWidth=5&bHideAnnounce=false&bHideEmergencyPan=true&strMapMarkerLabelMode=name&key=ABQIAAAAYbXZyR09wFj6QsiYucHpGxQEO34WZEWuIFq1A7yobGXPE-K5exQV9ZYR6NIkF8LCR8wsYvlhOIYsfA' />
        <embed id="IPRS_Dispatcher2" src="DispatcherMain.swf"
            flashVars='strLang=english&strIPRSSrvHost=&strGPSSrvHost=192.168.1.130&strGPSSrvSoapPort=8081&strGPSSrvFwdPort=26000&strLoginMode=simple&strSOSSrvHost=192.168.1.80&strSOSSrvSoapPort=8082&strSOSSrvFwdPort=26001&strSOSLoginMode=simple&strUserSIP=&strUserPswd=&nDelayForMapReadySecs=10&nGPSUpdatesRateSecs=120&nGPSSubscriptionsIntervalMinutes=10&nLat=35.0&nLng=32.5&nZoomLevel=5&strClientServiceVersion=2.1.36.19&nPathDotsSize=1&nPathWidth=5&bHideAnnounce=false&bHideEmergencyPan=true&strMapMarkerLabelMode=name&key=ABQIAAAAYbXZyR09wFj6QsiYucHpGxQEO34WZEWuIFq1A7yobGXPE-K5exQV9ZYR6NIkF8LCR8wsYvlhOIYsfA' 
            width="1400" height="1000" name="IPRS_Dispatcher" align="middle"
            play="true"
            loop="false"
            quality="high"
            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"> <!-- bgcolor="${bgcolor}" -->
        </embed>
</object>
```

I have added addcallback for the function i want to expose

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToFlash", callFromJavaScript);
```

FYI

```
  public function callFromJavaScript(str):void
  {
  LogAddItem( 30, str);
  }
```

In my IFRAME i have added the function

```
function callToFlash(str) 
{
  var swf = parent.top.$("#IPRS_Dispatcher");
  var bool = swf.sendToFlash(str);
}
```

Now getting error in chrome - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendToFlash'

UPDATE 25/06/2012 - output from **console.log(swf)**

```
[
<embed src=​"DispatcherMain.swf" width=​"100%" height=​"100%" align=​"middle" id=​"IPRS_Dispatcher" quality=​"high" name=​"IPRS_Dispatcher" wmode=​"opaque" allowfullscreen=​"true" allowscriptaccess=​"always" pluginspage=​"http:​/​/​www.adobe.com/​go/​getflashplayer" flashvars=​"strOEM=mt&strSplashImage=./​assets/​loadinglogo.jpg&strLang=english&strSelectableLangs=english,chinese, portuguese_brazil,german,french,spanish&strIPRSSrvHost=85.118.26.10&strGPSSrvHost=85.118.26.16&strGPSSrvSoapPort=8081&strGPSSrvFwdPort=26000&strLoginMode=simple&strUserSIP=&strUserPswd=&strSOSSrvHost=85.118.26.17&strSOSSrvSoapPort=8082&strSOSSrvFwdPort=26001&strClientServicePort=&strSOSLoginMode=simple&themeColor=a7c3e3&showRTTPriority=false&showGPSUpdateRate=true&nSamePosErrMeters=300&nDelayForMapReadySecs=10&nGPSUpdatesRateSecs=65535&nGPSSubscriptionsIntervalMinutes=10&nLat=48.311058&nLng=11.636753&nZoomLevel=13.0&strClientServiceVersion=2.1.36.04&bDispatcherEndsSessions=true&nSOSSubscriptionsIntervalMinutes=1&GPSKATime=20&SOSKATime=20&nPathDotsSize=2&nPathWidth=5&bHideAnnounce=false&bHideEmergencyPan=false&bHideDebugLog=false&showMutedColumn=false&strLogFilter=&strMapMarkerLabelMode=name&key=ABQIAAAAfJEcVYS6-jYp2UOUy8Wh5xSCeXAFBxztfWxjY5w1WzTnKjnSVRS7Uu5XoOIwTg2R_tq_c0QSCPxSHw" type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash">​
]
```

Comment: can you put it somewhere? like dropbox or jsfiddle or hosting? so I can help you with debugging?

Comment: IS that error a Flex error or a JavaScript error?

Comment: @www.eugenehp.tk sorry i can not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run please:

```
function sendToActionscript(str) 
{
  var swf = jQuery("#IPRS_Dispatcher", parent.document);
  console.log('step1');
  console.log(swf);
  console.log('step2');
  console.log.(swf.html());
  console.log('step3');

  swf.LogAddItem(30, str);
  console.log('step4');
}
```

Okay, next debug step: run this:

```
function sendToActionscript(str) 
{
  var swf = parent.top.$(“#IPRS_Dispatcher”);
  console.log('step1');
  console.log($);
  console.log('step2');
  console.log.(jQuery);
  console.log('step3');
  console.log(parent.document);
  console.log('step4');
}
```

EDIT

STEPS OUTPUT

```
step1 
function (j,s){return new b.fn.init(j,s)} iframecontent.html:49
step2 
[
<embed src=​"DispatcherMain.swf" width=​"100%" height=​"100%" align=​"middle" id=​"IPRS_Dispatcher" quality=​"high" name=​"IPRS_Dispatcher" wmode=​"opaque" allowfullscreen=​"true" allowscriptaccess=​"sameDomain" pluginspage=​"http:​/​/​www.adobe.com/​go/​getflashplayer" flashvars=​"strOEM=mt&strSplashImage=./​assets/​loadinglogo.jpg&strLang=english&strSelectableLangs=english,chinese, portuguese_brazil,german,french,spanish&strIPRSSrvHost=85.118.26.10&strGPSSrvHost=85.118.26.16&strGPSSrvSoapPort=8081&strGPSSrvFwdPort=26000&strLoginMode=simple&strUserSIP=&strUserPswd=&strSOSSrvHost=85.118.26.17&strSOSSrvSoapPort=8082&strSOSSrvFwdPort=26001&strClientServicePort=&strSOSLoginMode=simple&themeColor=a7c3e3&showRTTPriority=false&showGPSUpdateRate=true&nSamePosErrMeters=300&nDelayForMapReadySecs=10&nGPSUpdatesRateSecs=65535&nGPSSubscriptionsIntervalMinutes=10&nLat=48.311058&nLng=11.636753&nZoomLevel=13.0&strClientServiceVersion=2.1.36.04&bDispatcherEndsSessions=true&nSOSSubscriptionsIntervalMinutes=1&GPSKATime=20&SOSKATime=20&nPathDotsSize=2&nPathWidth=5&bHideAnnounce=false&bHideEmergencyPan=false&bHideDebugLog=false&showMutedColumn=false&strLogFilter=&strMapMarkerLabelMode=name&key=ABQIAAAAfJEcVYS6-jYp2UOUy8Wh5xSCeXAFBxztfWxjY5w1WzTnKjnSVRS7Uu5XoOIwTg2R_tq_c0QSCPxSHw" type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash">​
] 
step3 iframecontent.html:52
#document
step4
```

okay,so now simply try

```
function sendToActionscript(str) 
{
  var swf = parent.top.$(“#IPRS_Dispatcher”);
  swf.LogAddItem(30, str);
}
```

there is an error in your flex app
[image]

**Finally Resolved**

```
    // get flash movie object
var flashMovie;
function init() {
   if (document.getElementById) {
      flashMovie = parent.document.getElementById("IPRS_Dispatcher");
   }
}

// wait for the page to fully load before initializing
window.onload = init;

function callToFlash(str) 
{
  var bool = flashMovie.sendToFlash(str);
}
```

I think waiting for the page to fully load before initializing was the fix.

You can also use http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(init);
```

to get it working after DOM initialisation.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( from this, i removed step 2 and the error clears. i now get  - step1
[]
step3
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'LogAddItem'

Comment: looks like var swf = jQuery("IPRS_Dispatcher", parent.document); isnt capturing the object i need :(

Comment: try next step. What browser you're in?

Comment: take a look here http://dushyantpatel.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/how-to-access-element-of-parent-window-from-an-iframe-with-jquery/ you need to load query into each frame

Comment: next step error - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method '$'

Comment: looks like you didn't include jQuery source into your webpage. remember you need to include both into both html pages you're using.

Comment: and let me know. also I hope you know how to use google chrome web inspector?

Comment: correct! sorry, now i have added jQuery to both documents i see the parent.document ok

Comment: run steps again, and let me know the output. tnx :)

Comment: ok, now i get Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'LogAddItem'. possibly a separate issue?

Comment: updated my question with the latest code, still getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendToFlash' error?

Comment: I get back to you in couple hours, if you can make some test sample to use it locally, it would really help us to increase speed of getting this done :)

Comment: can you try to **console.log(swf)** and post the output from that point?

Comment: sorry for the delay, i was moving house this weekend.. anyway i have updated my question with the output. thanks

Comment: try to call **var swf = parent.top.$(“#IPRS_Dispatcher2”);**

Comment: captures nothing - to see full source of the swf page view the source of this http://usa-dispatcher.mobiletornado.com/test/IPRS_Dispatcher.html

Comment: how about to create JS function in top iframe and call it from JS function from GMap IFrame. And that JS function from top IFrame should be placed in the <head> section and should be binder by ExternalInterface smooth and nice.

Comment: ok, i have tried this way also. and getting same issue Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendToFlash'. Is there a problem with my ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToFlash", callFromJavaScript)? and does it matter where it is placed?

Comment: yes, ExternalInterface will bind it in the parent window, so there should be function with such name. Just get the classic version of JS<-->AS communications working. And then extend it by calling JS method of parent window from child iframe. If you see 'no method' exception, this means that you didn't handle JS function right in the top window.

Comment: fixed noe, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: hi Vince, glad you got it working. Use debug version of flash player :) And mark this answer as accepted :) Good luck to you with your project.