# iFrame parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent

When I attempt to access the parent node of an iframe. I get an undefined value returned.

```
var a = window.frames;

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    var val = a[i].document.getElementById("image_url").value;

    if(val != ""){
        a[i].parentNode //This doesn't return the parent div that the iframe is nested in
    }
}

<div>
    <iframe src="uploader.php"></iframe>
</div>
```

How can I access the parent node of an iframe element that is on the same page

Edit: I solved this by accessing the iframes with

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
```

Instead of

```
window.frames;
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. Is `iframe.parentNode` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Charlie I have attempted that, but it returns undefined instead of the parent node.

Comment: @John Revert your edit, and post the solution as an answer. EDIT: Either your question or your answer doesn't make sense. When `a` is a NodeList of `<iframe>` elements, then `a[i].document` is `undefined`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access parent Iframe from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

Comment: @RobW contentDocument is used when not using the frames elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's [$.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) you could do the following:

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    var $el = $('#image_url', this).closest('div');
    console.log($el);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [frameElement.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement).