# Access parent document from dynamic iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, cross-browser

This question is continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928139/how-to-change-iframe-styles-from-iframe-itself-using-jquery). I use the following code to append the dynamic `<iframe>` to the document.

```
var _hf_iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("id", "_hf_iFrame");
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("name", "_hf_iFrame");
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("allow-transparency", true);
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("style", "height: 354px; width: 445px; border: 0; top: 23%; position: fixed; left:0; overflow: show; background:transparent;");
document.body.appendChild(_hf_iFrame);
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("src", "javascript:false");

var myContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
+ '<html><head><title>Helpflip</title><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://somedomain.com/js/core.js"></script></head>'
+ '<body style="margin: 0px;"></body></html>';

_hf_iFrame.contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
_hf_iFrame.contentWindow.document.write(myContent);
_hf_iFrame.contentWindow.document.close();
```

When the `<iframe>` has loaded, I am trying to animate it using the following code

```
$('#_hf_iFrame', top.document).animate({
      'margin-left': '-400px'
   }, 300).animate({
      'margin-left': '-380px'
   }, 150).animate({
      'margin-left': '-393px'
}, 100);
```

This works fine on Firefox, Chrome and on Safari. IE 9 throws `Access Denied` on line `$('#_hf_iFrame', top.document)`

Does the problem of cross domain still apply?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try leaving out the `.src` line (so no `.src` on the iframe) as it is not required.  IE may be thinking that you're trying to do a cross-domain access.

Comment: Hi Libin, Just being curious why you are writing HTML of IFRAME in JavaScript. Wouldn't be better if you make a static HTML page and give that URL to IFRAME. And Problem of CrossDomain can exist as the SRC DOMAIN of IFRAME will not be same as parent page.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes... but with no success...

Comment: @PurusottamKaushik Hey, I had tried that but then IE, FF and chrome threw "Access Denied" due to the Same Origin Policy and I was not able to animate or even access the `<iframe>` but now I can access it on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Are you running the HTML page off your own hard disk?  There can be cross-origin issues when running off the local drive instead of off a real web server.

Comment: @jfriend00 tried that too.. even I am able to set `document.domain` to match parent document on all browsers. So the Cross origin will not be an issue, I guess..