# Accessing the Parent Document from an iFrame in IE

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permission Denied IE iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953158/permission-denied-ie-iframe)
>   [Access parent document from dynamic iframe using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947122/access-parent-document-from-dynamic-iframe-using-jquery)

I am trying to access the parent document from a dynamic `<iframe>` child using `$('#_hf_iFrame', top.document)`. It works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but IE throws an **Access Denied** exception.

I am using following code to create the `<iframe>` dynamically.

This question is continuation of this question. I use the following code to append the dynamic  to the document.

```
var _hf_iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("id", "_hf_iFrame");
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("name", "_hf_iFrame");
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("allow-transparency", true);
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("style", "height: 354px; width: 445px; border: 0; top: 23%; position: fixed; left:0; overflow: show; background:transparent;");
document.body.appendChild(_hf_iFrame);
_hf_iFrame.setAttribute("src", "javascript:false");

var myContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
+ '<html><head><title></title><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://somedomain.com/js/core.js"></script></head>'
+ '<body style="margin: 0px;"></body></html>';
_hf_iFrame.contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
_hf_iFrame.contentWindow.document.write(myContent);
_hf_iFrame.contentWindow.document.close();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to ask the same thing as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947122/access-parent-document-from-dynamic-iframe-using-jquery.  Only one question on a given topic.  If your other question isn't clear enough (which does seem to be a problem), then edit it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am sorry for creating multiple questions on the same topic..

Comment: Looks like it may be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886547/access-is-denied-javascript-error-when-trying-to-access-the-document-object-of

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you so much... that link was helpful. But please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This might fix your problem.

[Cross Sub Domain Javascript](http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.domain = "yourdomain.com";
</script>
```

> Basically, JS believes that even a subdomain such as
>   img.yourdomain.com is a different domain from www.yourdomain.com.
>   Because of that, AJAX across pages from those two subdomains will not
>   work. Also if you have an iframe from one to another, you will not be
>   able to refence JS vars or functions back and forth.

Comment: I have updated my question... I hope that now it's clear..

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code to

```
//var source = "javascript:void((function(){document.open();document.domain=\'cloudapp.net\';document.close();})())";  
var source = "javascript:false";
var elem = document.createElement("iframe");
elem.frameBorder = "0";
elem.src = source;
elem.style.width = "100%";
elem.style.margin = "0px";
elem.style.padding = "0px";
elem.setAttribute("id", "_hf_iFrame");
document.body.appendChild(elem);

elem.contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
elem.contentWindow.document.write(myContent);
elem.contentWindow.document.close();
```

and it working on all browsers... but still I couldn't find the reason for the strange issue.

Answer (score -1):

If both parent and iframe are on the same domain they i think you can get the Parent object from the iframe. Otherwise child iframe or parent cannot access each other.

To set the domain

```
document.domain = 'yourdomain.com';
```

**Edited:**

document.domain can only be set to a `subset of the current domain`. So `developer.mozilla.org` can be set to `mozilla.org`, but not `mozilla.com`. This property may also be read-only in some browsers.

Comment: `document.domain` can only be set to a subset of the current domain.  So `developer.mozilla.org` can be set to `mozilla.org`, but not `mozilla.com`.  This property may also be read-only in some browsers.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain) for more info.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have set the `document.domain` on both document without any error and a `alert(document.domain);` reflects the same. But still IE breaks on `$('#_hf_iFrame', top.document)`.

Comment: @LibinTK see the updated portion...