# JavaScript Id Handling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a website that allows users to open multiple pages of the same content in the same browser window via inline 'windows'.

As the **content can be repeated multiple times** the id's can in turn be the same and therefore I have to "handle" them each so that I can distinguish between these pages.

I currently do this by assigning on load a unique id to the script like so:

```
var id_key;

 function load_page() {
     id_key++;
     load_script("test.js") //load javascript file
 }
 //test.js:
 $(function () {
     var unique_id = id_key;
     //adds the `unique id ` to the end of all elements  with an id attribute set. ie `mycontainer` becomes `mycontainer_1`
     update_ids(unique_id);

     $("#mybtn_ " + unique_id).click(function () {
         //do stuff
     });
 }
```

This works fine most of the time however if multiple pages are loaded too fast the Id tends to get overwritten causing confusion and errors.

I am wondering if there is a better technique of this doing this. I have heard of backbone.js but I am not sure whether that would be helpful in this case.

Comment: `id_key=id_key++;`? Just `id_key++;` will do the trick there.

Comment: Good point fixed that.

Comment: You could load `"test.js?id=" + id_key` instead and let the script find out how it was called OR load the script only once and have one function to draw the whole interface (with id as an argument)

Comment: If I did test.js?id=" + id_key how could the script recover that id and also wouldn't mean that it won't be cached.

Comment: Can't you use `this` to find the clicked element and then just use [Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There are several general approaches to solve this kind of problem:

1. Load the sub pages in `iframe`s. Each iframe gets it's own ID space. Scripts in all frames can talk to each other via [the `parent` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript) as long as all [documents were loaded from the same domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
2. Don't use any ids. Instead, give each "window" an ID and then locate elements in the window via classes and parent-child relations. Note that an element can have more than one class.

   You can then use `$(selector, win)` to look for elements on a certain window `win`. The window becomes the "[Selector Context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)" which means jQuery will search only children of the window and nothing else.
3. At the start of your script, locate all important elements by ID and save them in a JavaScript object. That way, you can access them without using a jQuery selector.

   For example, you could select anything with an ID and save it with [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/data-storage/) in the window element. After this setup, all elements would be accessible via `$(win).data('id')`

Comment: Interesting suggestions. I'm taking a Html 5 approach to things so I want to avoid the Iframes but the class thing could be ok. Only problem is that it would make finding elements a lot harder. Also not sure whether adding non existent classes is good.

Comment: With regards to the third approach wouldn't not be essentially cloning them. Could be bad performance wise.

Comment: Also with regards to the second suggestion I think I'd still have the same issue I have now in terms of handling the id or win value. I still need to somehow get that value to the script file.

Comment: You must modify the script file to use your approach instead of looking up elements by ID. There is no cloning in any of my approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate quite good unique ids by concatenating a date and a random number:

```
new Date().getTime() + Math.random()
```

While this is by no means perfect, I think in your use case it will suffice.

As Jack mentioned in his comment, you can pass this id to your new window as a get parameter. I once did a whole OS-like interface with this method, and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: The issue I am having isn't to do with the "randomness" of the id but rather the handling of it. Using just numbers 1-100 is more then fine. The issue though is that the "id" itself can get overwritten if another page/window is loaded before the other has finished running its code.