# Using javascript to change frames

Tags: javascript, frames

I'm trying to change the element in one frames html with controls contained inside another frame. I can't however get it right to achieve this.

I basically have this:

```
<a href = "#"  id = "c1" onclick = "document.getElementById('text').color =     'red'">red</a>
```

which is meant to change this.

```
<p id = "text">dsdsdsdsd</p>
```

I can't however figure out how to do this the right way.

Edit:

The main page for this looks as follows:

```
<frameset cols = "15%, *" frameborder="100" border="1" framespacing="1">
<frame src ="bookMenu.html" scrolling = "no"/>
<frameset rows = "*, 10%" frameborder="100" border="1" framespacing="1">
    <frame src ="book1_intro.html" scrolling= "yes" name = "main"/>
    <frame src ="book_controls.html" scrolling= "no" name = "control"/>
</frameset>
```

The Calling button is in the framed named control and the destination is in the frame named main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have `frame`s, set a `name` attribute for the `frame` elements in `frameset`(s). Then you can refer to the `#text` from any frame (or `frameset` document) like this:

```
var text = top.window.main.document.getElementById('text');
```

Notice, that if this is a local page, you can't refer `(i)frame`s, when using Chrome. However, there's a workaround for this: add `--allow-file-access-from-files` to the target path of the Chrome icon, and open Chrome by clicking this modified icon before opening the frameset file.

Comment: at the moment I have this: top.window.main.document.getElementById('text').style.color for linking down into a nested frameset, should I be using parent then ? cause it doesn't seem to want to work either way

Comment: @Crossman `top.window` should work here, providing `book_controls.html` is not a `frameset` page too. Please make sure you've unique values in `id`s, and that `#text` exists. Also prefer using real closing tags for `<frame>`s, frames and framesets are not a part of HTML5.

Comment: @Crossman "`#text exists`" in my previous comment includes also situations, when `main` maybe not loaded or `#text` is not appended yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to the parent first, then a reference to the frame that contains your paragraph tag and use contentDocument to get at the document within that frame.

See:

[How to access parent Iframe from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

[How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)

Comment: Do you mean something like this: onclick = "parent.main.currentDocument.getElementById('text').style.color = 'red'

Comment: `document.querySelector('[name=authFormiFrame]').contentDocument.getElementById('userName')`