# Getting parent value in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below two html files. In `PassValueIFrame.html`  i have an iframe which refers `inputForm.html`. Also, i have one hidden field in `PassValueIFrame.html` and am trying to retrieve its value in `inputForm.html` but am not getting its value it alerts as '`undefined`'. Am i doing any wrong here? Please help me.

### PassValueIFrame.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>IFrame Example</title>
  </head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" class="Language" value="English">
<iframe name="iframe" id="iframe_id" src="inputForm.html" height="150" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

### inputForm.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().find('.Language').html());
  });

  </script>
   <title>IFrame Child Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Iframeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee </h1>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is happens because it's an iframe...

Comment: John, cannot iframe access a field from its parent?

Comment: I guess this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/935127/1420197

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<input id="myInput" type="hidden" class="Language" value="English">

$("#myInput", window.parent.document).val();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
alert(parent.document.getElementsByClassName("Language")[0].value);
```

or add id (for example `languageId`) to the hidden element and try

```
alert(parent.document.getElementById("languageId").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is define a function in the parent window and call it from the iframe:

## inputForm.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            window.parent.parent_function("Papa!");
        });
    </script>
    <title>IFrame Child Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Iframeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

## PassValueIFrame.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>IFrame Example</title>
    <script>
        function parent_function(str) {
            window.alert(str);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" class="Language" value="English">
    <iframe name="iframe" id="iframe_id" src="inputForm.html" height="150" >
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```