# Cannot get parent window from itself

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following problem:

I open an url in an iframe:

```
<iframe src="" name="framenamex" id="idframex"

<a href="urlsamedomainx" target="framenamex"...
```

but then when I want to hide the iframe from within the iframe:

```
javascript:parent.document.getElementById('idframex').style.visibility='hidden'
```

nothing happens, it seems like the iframe has no parent because when I call the `parent.location` or `window.top.location` I get nothing

please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access parent Iframe from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

Comment: Do URL of iframe and URL of parent belong to the same domain?

Comment: Yes both files are in the same server

Comment: meagar that is a diferent case, in my case I do have acces within anothers iframes but this one, meaby because I am putting the url in src from<a target=... I don't know

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, this isn't generally possible, otherwise any iframe would be able to access the page it is in and steal user data or other stuff.

If you control both the iframe code as well as the page code, you can get them to communicate. There are many tutorials and libraries to assist with this... here's one: http://viget.com/extend/using-javascript-postmessage-to-talk-to-iframes