# Not able to access opener document in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page which is embedded in iframe, from that page I open a popup window and I try to access document from opener object from popup window, getting the below error in JS Console.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin `https://<domain>` from accessing a frame  with origin "swappedout://". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "swappedout". Protocols must match.

PS: This is working fine in some of the Chrome versions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should determine what is the opener window of that popup. Is it the iframe from where you open the new popup window? Or the original page.

Then you can use js to get the document as the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3901057/966698)