# How to target parent ID outside an iframe jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How do I target `#main` from a button within an iframe using jQuery?

```
<div id="main">

<iframe><a class="click" href="#">a button inside a separate HTML</a></iframe>

</div>
```

I have this code:

```
$('.class').on('click', function(){
    $('#main', parent.document).animate({ 
            'bottom' : '0'
            });
});
```

What I wanted to do is when user clicks the button within the iframe(from a separate HTML document), it targets the `#main` then it will animate.

Comment: $('#main',window.parent.document).animate({
        'bottom' : 0
    });

*should work*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access parent Iframe from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

Comment: @JohnC It didnt work :( Is there something wrong with my codes?

Comment: is the iframe in thr same domain as the parent window?