# Access elements and its properties from <iframe> document to parent document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access element and its events and properties from child document which is in `<iframe>` and that `<iframe>` added into the page.

I have a survey and that I'm including into the page using `<iframe>`. I want to trigger events from the survey to so when I'm comes on survey page the **Lead** Facebook pixel code fires and when survey completed the **CompleteRegistration** Facebook pixel code fires. So I'm trying to access some actions/events from `<iframe>` to fires FB pixel code.

Both documents are on the same server, but it's not working.

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#assessment').load(function(){
    var iframe = $('#assessment').contents();
    iframe.find("h1 .state__title").click(function() { 
      alert("test");
    });
  });
});
```

Also this:

```
var a = window.frames['assessment'].contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('h1').innerHTML;
alert(a);
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the iframe in same domain as your document? Because of Same Origin Policy you can access iframe only from same domain (not sure if CORS would help to iframe).

Comment: @jcubic Yes, the iframe in same domain as your document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access parent Iframe from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

Comment: Your title is misleading as it reads like you want to access the parent from within the iframe, but from the text it becomes clear it is the opposite.

Comment: @trincot I just updated the title of the question

Answer (score 0):

First, add to your iframe an onload event, this onload will trigger a function that has two goals:

- send a message to the iframe to tell the content of that iframe that it has been loaded
- send page DOM to the iframe when requested

**[parent file]**

```
<iframe id="assessment" src="target.html" onload="check()">
    ...
</iframe>
```

and also we link the same action to the `window.onmessage` property, so that there will be a processing for each message received from the iframe.

**[parent file]**

```
window.onmessage = function(event) {
     check(event);
};
```

and the function:

**[parent file]**

```
function check(event) {
    if(!event || !event.data){
        // if the iframe is loaded, then tell it so
        document.getElementById('assessment').contentWindow.postMessage('','*');
    }else{
        // if the Window received a message from the iframe, then send
        // the page dom to the iframe
        event.source.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML, event.origin);
    }
}
```

And in the iframe, we will link `window.onmessage` to a function that has double goal:

- be confirmed that the iframe was loaded, so requests the data from parent
- receive dom from parent

**[child file]**

```
window.onmessage = function(event) {
    if(!event.data){
        // If the iframe was loaded, tell the parent to send
        // its dom
        window.parent.postMessage('get parent DOM',event.origin)
    }else{
        // If the parent sent its DOM, process it
        var dom = $('<div></div>').append(event.data);
        console.log(dom.html());
        ...
    }
};
```