# Allow Iframes to pull separate CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, css, iframe

We have a minimally styled product site that we give to our customers as an iframe to embed on their websites. We need to hide a certain menu item for some of the clients we give the link to. Is there a way we can add a variable to the iframe url or something in the iframe code itself where we could pull in a separate style sheet? or maybe use JS somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript

Comment: You could pass a parameter on the URL so that the code doesn't add the menu to the HTML.

Comment: You could try to use JS to [access the parent URL of the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe) and have a whitelist of URLs that will show the menu